# How can i prevent a particular file from being accessed in an Azure blob?

Tags: azure

I found a way to host a static website in an Azure blob, using a subdomain and an http re-direct

I do the following

1) In Azure I create a storage account with a container ( called docs ) that has Blob access policy.

2) I upload my static website to the docs container using the storage explorer. This includes some PHP files in a sub folder.

3) In the DNS I set up a cname record for a subdomain  ( called info say)
with alias myblob.blob.core.windows.net  ( where myblob is the name of my blob)

4) In the DNS I create an Http redirect for record to a file on the subdomain for www with url xhttp://info.mydomainname.com/docs/index.html ( spelt without the x. I put an x in front to prevent the hyperlink )

5) In Azure I create a custom domain for info.mydomainname.com

My website then works
however if someone knows the location of the PHP files then they can download them which means I must not store secrets in them.

Is there a way I can prevent them from being accessed?

I am using a Blob access policy for my container

Comment: Or should this be a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: Why are the PHP files in there in the first place? Blob storage will only serve static content, so it won't do anything with them anyway other than offer them up as static files. Why not just remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-guide)  I don't think it can be done.
As Sam points out they should not be there anyway.